# Orient DB upgrade is causing noSuchMethodError

Tags: java, orientdb, graph-databases

I have upgraded orient DB from 2.1.11 to orientdb-graphdb 3.1.4. After upgrade I am getting below error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseRecordThreadLocal.instance()Lcom/orientechnologies/orient/core/db/ODatabaseRecordThreadLocal;
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientBaseGraph.makeActive(OrientBaseGraph.java:407) ~[orientdb-graphdb-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientBaseGraph.openOrCreate(OrientBaseGraph.java:2000) ~[orientdb-graphdb-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is huge difference between 2.1.11 and 3.1.4. Just DB replacement will not help.
I recommend:

1. Perform data export from 2.1.11 (you can use OrientDB Console tool)
2. Install in parallel 3.1.4 (or even 3.1.5 - some bugs were fixed in between)
3. Make sure that your code and testcases adopted to OrientDB 3 and works perfect on db created from scratch on 3.1.4
4. Perform import to 3.1.4

Warning: I know that from our experience with this migration - not all imports will work perfectly, unfortunately. Some adjustments might be needed: sometimes you should clean problematic stuff in 2X, do export, do import, and then semi-manually import cleaned parts. That's why having 2.1.11 in parallel is highly recommended.